# local git repository and how to upload HTML and PHP code to webserver

Tags: php, html, git, upload

I'm new with git and still a bit confused how to best manage a local repository with a webserver. Until now, I've just used a plain text editor and FileZilla to upload HTML and PHP code to webserver.

Now I would like to use git for versioning and I've created a local repository on my Ubuntu desktop and made some changes to my code. Do I still have to use FileZilla to upload code to webserver or is there a more comfortable way with a git command? - All I found on the web was to use `push` and `pull`, but only in conjunction with GitHub - since I don't need to share my code it with others, I don't want to make my code public on GitHub.

Is there a git command to upload commited HTML and PHP files to webserver? Or have I misunderstood something? - Or shall I think about it that my repository is the code on the webserver?

Any help welcome.

Comment: I also run a 'private' git server, which i use as remote to all my projects. In that context, i can automate propagation with git. I 'push' from local repo to the git server, and in my instances, using a script, i 'pull' from the git repo to my web servers' and api servers, and etc ... the appropriate git repo/tag

Comment: Try using git hooks, after push a hook will be triggered then on your own machine rsync files to remote server. More git hooks on https://githooks.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After intensive research today, I found `git-ftp` and I think that this add-on is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you git installed on your server?

1. Push your code to your account repository on GitHub / Gitlab or Bitbucket
   2.In your html_public directory, run these commands

To initialize git in the folder

```
git init
```

To add your main remote where you will pull / push etc your code

```
git remote add origin https://your_remote_url.git
```

Recover the remote code

```
git pull origin the_branch_you_want_to_recover
```

or

```
git clone https://your_remote_url.git
```

or

```
git clone -u https://your_remote_url.git the_branch_you_want_to_recover
```

Comment: Maybe I was misunderstood - I don't want to clone my local repository to a external repository. This not what I am looking for - I don't want to copy `.git` - Files to webserver. I am just searching for a simple way to copy my actual committed code (html, css, php) to live webserver.